# Manipulating a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array called result that has a shape of (1200,67,67). Along the axis with length 1200 the array is correct. However, the other two axis have been flipped. I am getting:

```
result[0,:,:] = array([
    [-0.4182856 , -0.12402566, 0.26624826, ..., 0.65988034, 0.7642574, 0.4524528],
    [-0.39774683, -0.18033904, 0.14606595, ..., 0.7325263 , 0.75217724, 0.32839388],
    [-0.34418693, -0.15839723, 0.05166954, ..., 0.70598584, 0.57750726, 0.18543348],
    ...,
    [-0.5998102 , -0.512376 , -0.00168504, ..., 0.08733568, -0.28331557, -0.6596785 ],
    [-0.5967892 , -0.28394988, 0.03711865, ..., -0.03314218, -0.33655524, -0.671829 ],
    [-0.54678684, -0.21562685, 0.01694722, ..., -0.03415907,-0.36989942, -0.66516656]
], dtype=float32)
```

But I should be getting the second version.

```
result[0,:,:] = array([
    [0.45245281, 0.76425737, 0.65988034, ..., 0.26624826, -0.12402566, -0.41828561 ],
    [0.32839388, 0.75217724, 0.73252630, ..., 0.14606595, -0.18033904, -0.39774683],
    [0.18543348, 0.57750726, 0.70598584, ..., 0.051669542, -0.15839723, -0.34418693],
    ...
    [-0.65967852, -0.28331557, 0.087335683, ..., -0.0016850400, -0.51237601, -0.59981018 ],
    [-0.67182899, -0.33655524, -0.033142179, ..., 0.037118647,  -0.28394988, -0.59678918 ],
    [-0.66516656, -0.36989942, -0.034159068, ..., 0.016947223,  -0.21562685, -0.54678684]
], dtype=float32)
```

So I want to try to alter the 3d array to then flip the two axis of 67 length. Thanks.

Comment: your second `result` is not a valid simplification and contains only half the data of the first one. Are you looking to just reverse the inner most lists? I'll make an edit that tries to clear the presentation up a bit and take out the extra `]` from the second result. Please verify that what I do is correct.

Comment: Some of my formatting was off but fully fixed now, thanks!

Comment: So, conceptually, you want to just reverse each of the inner lists right?

Comment: Yes I tried something like `result_flipped = np.flip(result, axis= 2)` which means `result_flipped[0,:,:]` gives what I want. However, the 3D array result_flipped has not changed correctly.

Comment: the structure of the array looks incorrect.  also when you say, `dtype-=float32)`, presumably you mean `import numpy as np` and then `ndtype = np.float32`).  ie. the code is using the `numpy` module.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _the 3D array result_flipped has not changed correctly_? Based on my understanding of the desired output in your question, `flip(..., axis=2)` is exactly what you need. It would be helpful if you show the full 3d input and output for a small example array (maybe 3x4x4?)

Comment: `flip` does a negative step slice, `result[:, :, ::-1]`

Comment: I believe you need `result[..., ::-1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should be as simple as transposing the y and z axis. so the question can use the `transpose` function like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# Define the dimensions for the x, y, and z axes
x_dim = 1200
y_dim = 67
z_dim = 67

# Create a NumPy array with the specified dimensions initialized with zeros
original_array = np.zeros((x_dim, y_dim, z_dim))

# fill the array with your own specific numbers
# ...
# ...

# Flip the y and z axes using numpy.transpose
flipped_array = np.transpose(original_array, (0, 2, 1))

# Print the shape of the new array to confirm the axes have been flipped
print(flipped_array.shape)
```

I just show an array shape of zero's for the purpose of the example, but the OP can populate it with appropriate numbers.

The result is a new array with y and z flipped (same shape since y = z = 67):

```
(1200, 67, 67)
```

Comment: Your answer transposes the inner 67x67 matrices. OP wants to flip the innermost list. It'll be plainly obvious why your solution isn't what OP is looking for if you use any nonzero array as the input

Comment: For example, https://tio.run/##VZLPbuMgEMbvfgqUUyK5Ecwwf6jU6173AaJoZanp1lJqI8c95OmzY3C7NeIww3z8@AbI9/l9HPDx6D/yOM1u@PzId9fd3JCbZpz6v/3QXf9009Td3YstHku4P50aZ@P05I8xKCixa50lAaIHYm6dPwIzRIUSMyVVj3GJhSOQlDAS2NRz@03DJBJZsdJsCyZfpCGyNwoVAgIBoysxQRCBokFQTKgbXjR/nFYeWV0AF62nwJyoOvJmj7TEJEJequugFBGjnr@AC5FS0uCh9ksBUNbevQ@sVN16FURiLQVzhYFISmI9sCi5Hx7LSlqJSwvRLqtQUIK5p4o3SIRQkYhMREvXC1LsCdKGGI3IWssQiMGcFWLgFAVgJcZAyUu7ADlpSrEWmJfLIT431rl7ne/58mJP/3Yduxnh0DTN27XP@fL682PMUzfc8ni77LffpnV73zoDh4PtzFM/zPvdb5PsDmu21Z9M/Wzz/FXe/bLDvsWbk/9r3ePxDw

Comment: @pho,  thanks for the comment. it is not obvious from the example posted that this is the case.  where do you see that the OP wants to _"flip the innermost list"_ ?   i see this: _" I want to try to alter the 3d array to then flip the two axis of 67 length. "_

Comment: unless the question is ambiguous, this appears to be the correct answer.   I would be interested to see an alternative different answer.

Comment: `result_flipped = np.transpose( np.flip(result, axis= 2) , (1, 2, 0))` appears to have worked for me. There might be an easier way to do it but this gets the same as my expected 3D array.

Comment: @jim_athon, you may want the transpose, but your two `result[0,:,:]` don't show that.  Now if the second array was displayed as `result[:,;,0]`, I can see the transpose.  You should have explicitly told us what was wrong with the first `result`.